# replace generic with actual class

Tags: java

Is there a way to wrap this ugliness if i have a class that is suitable for a generic?

So this

```
public HasOne aMethod(Class<? extends Model> clazz){

    HasOne<Customer> hasOne = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<HasOne<Customer>>() {
    }));

    return hasOne;
}
```

would turn into something like this. (this obviously doesn't compile)

```
public HasOne aMethod(Class<? extends Model> clazz){

    HasOne<clazz> hasOne = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<HasOne<clazz>>() {
    }));

    return hasOne;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not

```
public <T extends Model> HasOne<T> aMethod(Class<T> clazz){

    HasOne<T> hasOne = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<HasOne<T>>() {
    }));

    return hasOne;
}
```

Comment: @MarlonBernardes yes... was primarily giving an idea

Comment: Just to clarify: now that you edited your post, it does compile (you changed from `... aMethod(Class<T extends Model>)` to `<T extends Model> HasOne<T> aMethod(Class<T> clazz)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T extends Model> HasOne<T> aMethod(Class<T> clazz){
    HasOne<T> hasOne = injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<HasOne<T>>() {
    }));
    return hasOne;
}

HasOne<Customer> customer = aMethod(Customer.class);
```